# HTML Anchor Jump Doesn't Work

Tags: css, html, anchor

The title means what it says. when i setup a link to jump to a certain div it doesn't work. For example when i say `<a href="#Section1>Section 1</a>` and click it, it should jump to the anchor tag with the name of 'Section1' `<a name="Section1"></>` but nothing happens.

```
<main id="Main">
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="Section-Links Left Box-Sizing">
            <div class="Links">
                <a href="#test">Test Post</a>
                <a href="#test2">Test Post</a>
                <a href="#test3">Test Post</a>
                <a href="#test4">Test Post</a>
                <a href="#test5">Test Post</a>
                <a href="#test6">Test Post</a>
                <a href="#test7">Test Post</a>
                <a href="#test8">Test Post</a>
                <a href="#test9">Test Post</a>
                <a href="#test10">Test Post</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Sections Left Box-Sizing">
            <div class="Section">
                <a name="Test"></a>
                <span class="Section-Title">Test Section</span>
                <p class="Section-Text">Some Random Words Here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Section">
                <a name="Test2"></a>
                <span class="Section-Title">Test Section</span>
                <p class="Section-Text">Some Random Words Here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Section">
                <a name="Test3"></a>
                <span class="Section-Title">Test Section</span>
                <p class="Section-Text">Some Random Words Here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Section">
                <a name="Test4"></a>
                <span class="Section-Title">Test Section</span>
                <p class="Section-Text">Some Random Words Here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Section">
                <a name="Test5"></a>
                <span class="Section-Title">Test Section</span>
                <p class="Section-Text">Some Random Words Here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Section">
                <a name="Test6"></a>
                <span class="Section-Title">Test Section</span>
                <p class="Section-Text">Some Random Words Here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Section">
                <a name="Test7"></a>
                <span class="Section-Title">Test Section</span>
                <p class="Section-Text">Some Random Words Here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Section">
                <a name="Test8"></a>
                <span class="Section-Title">Test Section</span>
                <p class="Section-Text">Some Random Words Here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Section">
                <a name="Test9"></a>
                <span class="Section-Title">Test Section</span>
                <p class="Section-Text">Some Random Words Here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Section">
                <a name="Test10"></a>
                <span class="Section-Title">Test Section</span>
                <p class="Section-Text">Some Random Words Here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Clear"></div>
    </div>

    <p class="Footer-Masthead">Created By Moussa Harajli.</p>
</main>
```

if you would like to test this go here. `http://67.184.73.19/Projects/Assassins/rules.php`

Comment: ahhhh there we go i didnt realize it was case-sensitive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anchor links doesn't point to `name`s but to `id`s

so change for example:

```
<a name="Test7"></a>
```

to:

```
<a id="Test7"></a>
```

And you should not change the capitalization of the ids in the id attribute and the links.

Comment: It used to... and still does

Answer (score 7):

Try setting the id in the `div` tag:

```
<div id="test" class="Section">...</div>
```

And this should work:

```
<a href="#test">Test Post</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind your problem is that you have different ID's in your links since `test2` is not the same as `Test2`.

Though... from my experience the `<a>` element is essentially redundant since the following works in all modern browsers:

```
<main id="Main">
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="Section-Links Left Box-Sizing">
            <div class="Links">
                <a href="#test">Test Post</a>
                <a href="#test2">Test Post</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Sections Left Box-Sizing">
            <div id="test" class="Section">
                <span class="Section-Title">Test Section</span>
                <p class="Section-Text">Some Random Words Here.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="test2" class="Section">
                <span class="Section-Title">Test Section</span>
                <p class="Section-Text">Some Random Words Here.</p>
            </div>
```